# How to get users course grade in sensei?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i need to get the user grade in a functions.php hook.
I tried it like this:

```
$course_id = intval($subuser->kurs_id);
$user_id = intval($subuser->anwender_id);

global $woothemes_sensei, $course;
$status = WooThemes_Sensei_Utils::sensei_course_user_grade($course_id, $user_id);
```

But this gives me only a float 0, the user i tried has 100%;

Anyone an idear? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it!

```
$status = Sensei()->course->get_completion_percentage($course_id, $user_id);
```